# How to set the unique environments for tasks on every node in docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Some arguments of `docker service create` allow to use template like `{{.Node.ID}}`. But unfortunately node labels are not supported.
What is the right way for a decision of this problem: I need to set the environment variables for every task.

Docker Engine: 19.03.2

For example:

```
docker service create --env SOME_ENV="{{.Node.Labels.SOME_NODE_LABEL_VALUE}}"
```

In this way, I need to configure `docker service task` especially for every swarm's node.